# Get all pairs from sublists which no pair being from one sublist alone

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a number of lists with a bunch of elements,

```
lists = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    [7, 1, 2, 3, 5],
    ["alpha", "gamma"],
    # ...
]
```

I would now like to create a list of all pairs of the individual elements in the above lists, i.e.,

```
combinations = [
    ["a", 7],
    ["a", 1],
    # ...
    ["c", "gamma"],
    [7, "alpha"],
    # ...
]
```

with the condition that both elements of the pairs are from different sublists. Sorting is not important, so one of `["a", 7]` and `[7, "a"]` is enough.

Any hints? (Perhaps something neat from `itertools`?)

Comment: Itertools won't get you far on its own, since its `permutations` and `combinations` methods only work on a single iterable. Would not comprehensions be better for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way: Make all combinations of 2 lists. Then do a product of the combinations.

```
from itertools import product, combinations, chain
res = list(chain.from_iterable(product(a, b) for a, b in combinations(lists, 2)))

print(res)
[('a', 7),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 2),
 ('a', 3),
 ('a', 5),
 ('b', 7),
 ('b', 1),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 3),
 ('b', 5),
 ('c', 7),
 ('c', 1),
 ('c', 2),
 ('c', 3),
 ('c', 5),
 ('a', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'gamma'),
 ('b', 'alpha'),
 ('b', 'gamma'),
 ('c', 'alpha'),
 ('c', 'gamma'),
 (7, 'alpha'),
 (7, 'gamma'),
 (1, 'alpha'),
 (1, 'gamma'),
 (2, 'alpha'),
 (2, 'gamma'),
 (3, 'alpha'),
 (3, 'gamma'),
 (5, 'alpha'),
 (5, 'gamma')]
```

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.combinations` + `itertools.product` and `set` comprehension to remove duplicates

```
{item for z in (itertools.combinations(x, 2) for x in itertools.product(*lists)) for item in z}


{('a', 'alpha'),
 ('a', 'gamma'),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 2),
 ('a', 3),
 ('a', 5),
 ('a', 7),
 ('b', 'alpha'),
 ('b', 'gamma'),
 ('b', 1),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 3),
 ('b', 5),
 ('b', 7),
 ('c', 'alpha'),
 ('c', 'gamma'),
 ('c', 1),
 ('c', 2),
 ('c', 3),
 ('c', 5),
 ('c', 7),
 (1, 'alpha'),
 (1, 'gamma'),
 (2, 'alpha'),
 (2, 'gamma'),
 (3, 'alpha'),
 (3, 'gamma'),
 (5, 'alpha'),
 (5, 'gamma'),
 (7, 'alpha'),
 (7, 'gamma')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it thanks to @domochevksi's comment:

```
n = len(lists)
combinations = [
    [item0, item1]
    for i in range(n)
    for j in range(i+1, n)
    for item0 in lists[i]
    for item1 in lists[j]
    ]
```

Comment: Glad it inspired you even though all the other answers seem to prove me wrong.